# Permiso de acceso para crear Carpeta con Mkdirs() en Android

Tags: android

Al intentar crear una carpeta con **mkdir**,en mi proyecto de Android con Api 26, la función **mkdir()** me arroja False. Tomando en consideración que para un **API mayor a 22** se piden los permisos en tiempo de ejecución, previamente al ejecutar mkdir, yo solicito la permisología correspondiente para WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, sin embargo, mkdir() no funciona, sino al cerrar y abrir nuevamente la App, al parece que en la segunda ocasión si reconoce los permisos y crea la carpeta.

```
 if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
            folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), Constants.NOMBRE_DIRECTORIO);

            if(!folder.exists()) {
                if(!folder.mkdir()) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
```

Como pudiera solucionar esta situación para que en la primera ocasión que el usuario otorga los permisos en tiempo de ejecución la función **mkdir**, trabaje correctamente.?

Comment: Los solicitas manualmente o solo en el AndroidManifest.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

trata agregando los respectivos permisos al manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

también coloca el siguiente código en el OnCreate del mainActivity

```
if(!haveStoragePermission()) {
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
     Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
 }, 1);
}
```

esta es la funcion de haveStoragePermission

```
public  boolean haveStoragePermission() {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
            return checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Comment: Gracias, pero no funciono, la primera vez que la corro, pide el permiso, le doy aceptar (allow), y cuando se ejecuta la instrucción mkdir, falla y la aplicación se cierra, luego entro nuevamente, y en la segunda ocasión ya no pide el permiso, y ejecuta la instrucción mkdir sin problemas.  Cabe decir que el código esta en un Fragment, tendrá eso que ver.?